# Getting value of specific item in combobox in Visual Basic 2013

Tags: combobox, visual-studio-2013

I'm having great difficulty trying to find how to simply get the text of one specific item in a ComboBox.

I have cmbSelectedHinge as a dropdownlist style. All I need is to know what the text is in position 0. I would have thought simply:

```
MsgBox(cmbSelectHinge.Items.IndexOf(0))
```

but no. It returns "-1" even though there is a line of text in it. It seems this question has never before been asked on the internet, and there's no useful information on MSDN.

Any help, *please*

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post but saw this while searching for something else.  Thought i'd thorw in an answer in case anyone else comes across it and needs it

```
MsgBox(cmbSelectHinge.Items(0).ToString)
```

Would give you the value in the very first position of the combobox

```
MsgBox(cmbSelectHinge.Items(1).ToString)
```

Would give you the value in the 2nd position